# Does TestFlight delete app data after you close the app on your phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, testflight

I have a small app that accepts user signups (name, email, phone, etc.), and I have logic to store a user ID on their device, after the signup process stores their data in Firebase. The ID allows the user to bypass the sign up process if they close the app and reopen it.

In Expo Go, the logic works as intended; a new user is transitioned from the splash screen to the signup screen if they've never signed up before. And if they've signed up before, the app will check for the stored user ID, and they're sent to a different screen.

In TestFlight, the user is always sent to the signup screen even if they've already signed up. This is my first time using TestFlight, so I'm wondering if TestFlight deletes that kind of stored data once a user closes the app. I've tried a couple different ways of writing the code, and I've been trying to find any official information on TestFlight around this scenario, but I haven't had any luck.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually specified what kind of storage, you're using for your data - which makes the question very ambigious.

However, the answer in any case to your question is: no. TestFlight does not delete the stored data when the user closes the app.

You must probably have chosen an incorrect manner of storing the user data. The recommended way to store data necessary for user login is to store it in the Keychain on the phone. This is what your app should do.